# I am having issues with page refreshing (google maps api) - php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, oop

I am trying to create a web app (with PHP and Ajax) where users can add locations on a map.
The problem is that when a marker is added on a zoomed map (when the user clicks), the page refreshes and it zooms out. I'd like it to stay at the "zoom level" that the user needs to add a marker. I am working with the google maps API.
Can someone maybe help me understand what I did wrong? I am still learning

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// variables location
let locationData=[];
var lat='47.3769';
var long='8.5417';

// geolocation active?
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showlocation)
function showlocation(p){
lat=p.coords.latitude;
long=p.coords.longitude;
  initilizaMap();
}
}

else{
  alert('Please Open Your Geolocation');
  initilizaMap();
}

// initialize map

    var red_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' ;
    var purple_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png' ;
function initilizaMap(){
    var locations = locationData;
 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon :   locations[i][3] === 'Active' ?  red_icon  : purple_icon,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        
      });
// click event to add location
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          
          
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }


      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          
 
//adding marker
 
     locationData.push(["<div>\n" +
              
              
                " <textarea class='form-control'   id='manual_description' data-lat="+event.latLng.lat()+"  data-lng="+event.latLng.lng()+" placeholder='Description'></textarea> <button class='btn btn-primary saveBtn btn-sm'  >Save</button>  " +
                " " +
                "</div>",event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng()])
      //creating info window instance
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'selected location'
  });


initilizaMap();

      //adding pointer click event to open infowindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

  });
  });


  }

//   AJAX function for the save button

 $('#map').on('click','.saveBtn',function(){
 var val=$(this).prev('textarea').val();
 var latitude=$(this).prev('textarea').attr('data-lat');
 var longitude=$(this).prev('textarea').attr('data-lng');
 if(val==''){
  alert('Please Enter Description');
 }
 else{
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:{latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude,description:val},
  url:'ajaxRoutes.php?addUserPost=1',  
  success:function(res){
  showdata();

  
  }
  })
  infowindow.close();
 }
 })
// submit the data (add data)
$('#form-1').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    url:'ajaxRoutes.php?addUserPost=1',
    success:function(res){
        showdata();
        $('#form-1')[0].reset();
    }
})
})

// submit the data (edit-->not working)
$('#form-2').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    url:'ajaxRoutes.php?updateUserPost=1',
    success:function(res){
        showdata();
        $('#form-2')[0].reset();
        $('#editModal').modal('hide')

    }
})
})


// show what user submits
// function to show data on the table
showdata()
function showdata(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
               data:{id:'<?php  echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>'},
            url:'ajaxRoutes.php?getUserPost=1',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
                var html='';
                var sno=0;
                locationData=[];
                for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                    sno++;
          var status="";
if(res[i].status=='Active'){
status='<h4>Status : '+res[i].status+'</h4> <a href="javascript:;"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deletBtn" data="'+res[i].id+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a><div>\n' +
                '<table class=\"map1\">\n' +
                '<tr>\n' +
                '<td><a>Description:</a></td>\n' +
                '<td><textarea disabled id=manual_description placeholder=Description>'+res[i].description+'</textarea></td></tr>\n' +
                '</table>\n' +
                '</div>';
}
else{
status="<div>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><a>Description:</a></td>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled id='manual_description' placeholder='Description'>"+res[i].description+"</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</div>";
}

                     locationData.push([status,res[i].latitude,res[i].longitude,res[i].status,res[i].description])
                    html+='<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+sno+'</td>'+
                            // '<td>'+res[i].latitude+'</td>'+
                            // '<td>'+res[i].longitude+'</td>'+
              '<td>'+res[i].description+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+res[i].status+'</td>'+
                            '<td><a href="javascript:;"  class="btn btn-dark editBtn" data="'+res[i].id+'" data1="'+res[i].latitude+'" data2="'+res[i].longitude+'">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:;"  class="btn btn-danger deletBtn" data="'+res[i].id+'">Delete</a></td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#showdata').html(html);
                initilizaMap()
            }
        })
  }
  

 
$('#showdata').on('click','.editBtn',function(){
$('#editModal').modal('show');
$('input[name=latitude1]').val($(this).attr('data1'))
$('input[name=longitude1]').val($(this).attr('data2'))
$('input[name=id]').val($(this).attr('data'))
})


$('#main-cont').on('click','.deletBtn',function(){

let id=$(this).attr('data');
var txt;
var r = confirm("Do you want to Delete this Location!");
if (r == true) {
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    data:{id:id},
    url:'ajaxRoutes.php?deleteUserPost=1',
    success:function(res){
        showdata();
    }
})
}
})

</script>
```

Thank you very much in advance!